# prepopulate numpy array with fixed values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I prepopulate while initializing numpy array with fixed values?
I tried generating `list` and using that as a `fill`.

```
>>> c = np.empty(5)
>>> c
array([0.0e+000, 9.9e-324, 1.5e-323, 2.0e-323, 2.5e-323])
>>> np.array(list(range(0,10,1)))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> 
 
>>> c.fill(np.array(list(range(0,10,1))))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

>>> c.fill([np.array(list(range(0,10,1)))])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Expected -

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.tile(np.arange(10), (5,1))`

[`np.arange(10)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) creates an array of integers from 0 to 9

[`np.tile(..., (5,1))`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) tiles copies of the array - 5 copies going "down" (new rows) and 1 "across" (1 copy within each row)

Comment: You can also use the python built-in [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) instead of `arange`, which creates an iterator (rather than an array), to the same affect

Answer (score 3):

`fill` fills each entry with the same value. `c = np.empty(size); c.fill(5)` allocates an array of size `size` without initialising any values and then fills it with all `5`.

In addition to the answer by AJ Biffl, you can also assign values to an ndarray via broadcasting:

```py
c = np.empty(5)
c[:] = range(5)
```

This only works if the shapes match, but it does let you do stuff like this:

```py
a = np.empty((5, 3))
a[:] = [range(i, i+3) for i in range(5)]

>>> array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [2., 3., 4.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

Comment: To be clear for this case, the example array can be constructed with `c = np.empty((5,10), dtype = int); c[:,:] = range(10)`